# SSRS - No admin rights for default user

Tags: reporting-services

I am setting up a SQL Server reporting server on my local machine. The setup works just fine, but whenever I go to the reports starting page my standard user does not have any admin rights and therefore I can do basically nothing:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea what the reason for that is?

Best regards,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You will need to login to the webportal using an account that belongs to the local administrators group on your local machine, or the account that installed SSRS as that account, by default, would have been added to the admin group.

Once you have logged in you should be able to add users via the Site Settings menu in the webportal

[image]

Comment: Hello Alan. That is my issue here. I am logged in with the user that installed everything and that user doesn't have admin rights. That issue only exists on my work computer, it works perfectly fine with my private notebook.

Comment: I guess you are not a local admin on your work computer. If can check from the command line using `gpresult /v /scope user` . It takes a few seconds to run. Then check if `BUILTIN\Adminstrators` is listed in the groups. If not then I guess a call to your IT department is in order